# How to pass URL parameters from one domain to other?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

I have 2 sites with one Google Tag Manager container. I need to pass parameters from site A to site B via URL. I can easily append values to the URL using JS but it is getting stripped once the user arrives on-site B.

Any ideas on how this can be done?